# Посоветуйте метод для поиска оптимальных путей по сайту

Tags: алгоритм, r, анализ-данных, поиск-пути

Задача - найти наиболее выгодные пути пользователей с точки зрения денег, т.е. поиск путей, при которых конверсия в покупку наибольшая.

Например

экран 1 -> экран 2 -> экран 3 - cr = 1%

экран 1 -> экран 3 -> экран 2 - cr = 2%

Пробовал строить санкеи, но они не решили задачу. С цепями Маркова тоже не задалось. Может есть какой-то аналогичный метод или вы как-то решали похожие задачи? Достаточно просто наводки для гугла, а если есть пример на R так вообще замечательно.

На выходе хочется что-то подобное получить

[image: markov_chains]

Comment: Можете уточнить, чем вам Sankey не подошли, может быть вы просто не умеете ими пользоваться? (или вы их не в ту сторону развернули - вам же нужно все покупки слева, а пути справа?)

Comment: Там получается уж очень много всего, поверхностно закрывает вопрос конечно, фавориты в глаза бросаются сразу, но хотелось бы чуть углубиться. Вырезать малозначимые шаги, например.

Answer (score 0):

upd. Всё таки цепи маркова тут лучше всего подходят, вопрос снимается